# Delegate / Timer - Method (misunderstanding?)

Tags: c#, multithreading, methods, timer, delegates

There's many questions and articles on timer scripts, but oddly enough, I haven't succeeded in uh, this one. Is it just (?) a simple delegate - timer. I would post errors but it is probably a rough understanding of the timing class.

```
class Core
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer systimer, sysupdate;
    delegate void MyDelegate(string s);
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Core dtimer = new FunctionTimer();
         Core dupdate = new Update();
         TimerCallback tcb1 = Core.FunctionTimer;
         TimerCallback tcb2 = Core.Update;
         systimer = new Timer(tcb1, null, 0, 1);
         sysupdate = new Timer(tcb2, null, 0, 1);
    }
}
```

I'm assuming the actual methods are sort of irrelevant..

Comment: So what is the actual problem you're facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) create new instance of a timer, pass in millisecond duration

```
systimer = new Timer( 10 * 60 * 1000 ); // 10 minutes
```

2) hookup event handler (delegate) to execute when duration elapses

```
systimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandlder( nameOfHandler );
```

3) start timer

```
systimer.Start();
```

Comment: I overlooked adding (object Object, ElapsedEventArgs e) for the methods.